# I had a physical fight in work. But then my father interfere. now i think they want to fire me

Tags: colleagues, internship, team, manager, relationships

I am a free apprentice in a small size Software company(about 30 employees) for about 2 years during my college career. in these years I had no Argue or any Moral Problem at all. every was fine. I had made one application for the company and it was ready to publish.  I felt that I am going to be required and I've had a happy time. They even Removed me From Apprentices room to Employees Room That's Awesome! :). just 2 months ago I started to spend my university internship(which is a 40 days career) in this company too.

But a few days ago I've had a physical fight with one of my teammates who is an employee. I DID NOT start the fight. we had a very small verbal argue and then "He" turned it to physical that others immediately interfered and made us stop(I have to say that during the fight I did not punch or anything that was physical. I just told him that I have never Insulted him and he shouldn't fight with me) Every person who was in that room knows that it was absolutely his fault and I did not do anything wrong.

After that, I immediately Called my father because he always gives me best suggestions. He told me to talk to the Company Manager(because I thought our team leader will not do anything and if do, it would be too late and I was sure he can not handle this problem because if he could, he would not make this happened. because he had known that my teammate and I have some very Serious problems)(I have to mention that I mean "CEO" when I say the word "Manager"). I spoke with the manager and He told that he will speak with my co-worker and speaks again with me too to solve the problem. So tomorrow of that day my father (Who was a great manager with a lot of experiences) and I went to the company.(I should have known that bringing him is wrong). my father went in manager office and I went to our room.

Then my manager called my teammate and our team leader to met them. after about 15 minutes they came back and my team leader asked me to speak to me in private.

He told me that calling my father was Completly wrong and here is not a school.
And then he said that you won't do any projects for the company From this day and everything you will do during your internship is your personal coding.(Damn so That App which was ready to publish is canceled!).
And At last, he told me that I have to get my Stuff and back to apprentices room! (I expected that my manager will tell my teammate to apologize me because I was not a simple apprentice. I was (sort of) one of the company's family member. everybody trusts me and are really kind to me!.)

I know that it was completely wrong to bring my father, But I didn't think that it cause a bigger problem.I'm just worried about the future. **Are they Still want's to keep me? Am I Going to be fired when my university internship finishes? if so is there anything I can do to make things better and save myself. Any tips that can save me from this puddle that I've made for myself.**

And if there is nothing that I can do for this situation and I'm going to be fired after my university internship finished, **what is the best decision Right now?**
Update: **After All of them, When I saw my manager how should I behave?**

At last, I'm sorry if I had any grammar issue.
Thanks for further helps.

Comment: I know it is really long but I want to share all the details with you so if there is any problem in my question, let me know.

Comment: You already know the problem, what is stopping you from fixing it? We don't need to know your life history, just stick to what is relevant to the question. Oh, speaking of which, what is your question?

Comment: "Are they Still want's to keep me?" - Only they can answer this.

Comment: This is unclear, did you just call your father for advice or did you actually get him involved? There's nothing wrong with consulting an elder for advice and no one should criticize you for that. But beyond that they need to stay out of it.

Comment: @Seth_R i just called him for advice but he became worried and wanted to know what did happened. But unfortunatly it just make manager and others more sad.

Comment: Physical fight? And you're not fired yet? Even if you did not began the fight, you'd have been fired immediatly in all the software shops I did work in.

Comment: TBH your father as a "great manager with a lot of experiences" should *absolutely* have known better than to go to your workplace. This situation is almost as much his fault as yours.

Comment: @brhans I know I made mistake with letting him come to the company, But he had his own reasons. But it does not matter now. It Happened and I can do Almost nothing about it. I can only listen to "Kilisi" Suggestion and Learn a lesson from my mistake: "NEVER Let anyone interfere "Directly" in your Decisions(But do not forget Counsel at all!)". :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You messed up but you're just starting, there's lots of companies and lots of years left for you. Finish your internship there if you can and learn a lesson.

Some people can be pretty unkind to those starting out since you're viewed as know-nothing-kids. But the age issue fixes itself in time, just let it slide off and remain outwardly cheerful.

Just soldier on, the boss was a starting kid once as well, a bit of time and he may well rethink his options. I've forgiven a few young chaps in my time after the keen edge of anger wore off. Nothing you can do about it anyway.

Comment: Good advice. Regardless of what happens to this job, do not depend on your father for job-related advice in the future. He made a bad mistake by coming to your workplace and trying to influence your employer, and does not have the excuse of youth and inexperience.

Comment: I think that may be a bit too strong; yes the father may a bad error, but his bias in the situation may have clouded his judgement.  That doesn't necessarily mean all of his future advice will be bad.  But of course I agree, never physically bring him in again to resolve an issue because doing so is very unprofessional.  Lesson learned (and not a big deal in the grand scheme of things; we all make mistakes--the important thing is to learn from them).

Comment: The manager/CEO is being a jerk too, but recognize his position. Physical alterations == legal trouble brewing. Father comes in == more legal trouble brewing. Your manager does not need or want employees with this kind of baggage.

Comment: @Dúthomhas the guy's been fired from this job for 2 years, don't rub it in

Comment: Oops! I don’t know why this thread popped up to the top of my stack, but I failed to look at the date before responding. Sorry about that.